# How to increase the forms / panel size JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I will begin with the explanation that what is supposed to do the program below. Well, when you click on the button expands on the text, along with the text steadily increasing width and / or height. In such a manner, that the entire text is visible all the time.

The problem is that when zoomed button does not increase the display area so that just a few clicks starts hiding. The program itself should increase the display area so that everything is visible all the time.

Screen publishes what it looks like and how it should be.

[image: Picture of requirements.]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String ... args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame");
        final GridLayout gd = new GridLayout(0,1);
        frame.setLayout(gd);

        final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        final JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        final JButton btn2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        btn1.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            int fontSize = 14;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
                btn1.setFont(font);
                fontSize++;     
            }
        });

        btn2.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            int fontSize = 14;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
                btn2.setFont(font);
                fontSize++;
            }
        });


        panel1.add(btn1);
        panel2.add(btn2);
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.add(panel2);


        //frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();       
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

  }
}
```

Comment: Rather then creating a new font, try using Font#deriveFont which will allow you to change properties of an existing font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that when zoomed button does not increase the display
>   area so that just a few clicks starts hiding. The program itself
>   should increase the display area so that everything is visible all the
>   time.

add code line `frame.pack();` after `Font` increased / decreased, then all `JComponents` in the `JFrame` will be relayout